# app is re-initializing the first time ADAL "protected" URL is accessed via $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure-active-directory, adal

I have page based loosely off the Angular SPA ADAL sample found [here](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-WebAPI-AngularJS-DotNet)

After returning from the MS login page upon accessing my API that is secured with AAD the angular  .config() function is called 3 times. This breaks updates to scope that was initiated in the first instance of the app. After this initial thrashing everything works as expected. Even reloading the page does not reproduce this issue. It only occurs this first time after logging in.

It this normal with ADAL? Is there a way to avoid this?
Am I not updating $scope correctly from AJAX call backs?

Below is some key code snippets:

app.js:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'AdalAngular'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, adalProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider.when("/visit", {
    controller: "visitCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/ngViews/Visit.html",
    requireADLogin: false,
}).when("/visit/:visitNumber", {
    controller: "visitCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/ngViews/Visit.html",
    requireADLogin: false,
}).when("/", {
    controller: "homeCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/ngViews/Home.html",
    requireADLogin: false,
}).when("/teamwork", {
    controller: "teamworkCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/ngViews/Teamwork.html",
    requireADLogin: false,
}).when("/mywork", {
    controller: "myWorkCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/ngViews/MyWork.html",
    requireADLogin: false,
}).when("/dashboard", {
    controller: "dashboardCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/ngViews/Dashboard.html",
    requireADLogin: false,
}).when("/error", {
    templateUrl: "/ngViews/Error.html",
    controller: "errorCtrl",
    requireADLogin: false,
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' }); // needed to avoid a bug in ADAL see: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/42


var endpoints = cmSettings.adalEndpoints;
//$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); // breaks ADAL
adalProvider.init(
    {
        instance: cmSettings.aadInstance,
        tenant: cmSettings.tenant,
        clientId: cmSettings.clientId,
        extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
        endpoints: endpoints,
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.  
        // Also, token acquisition for the To Go API will fail in IE when running on localhost, due to IE security restrictions.
    },
    $httpProvider
    );
}]);
```

controller:

```
'use strict'
angular.module('app')
.controller('navBarCtrl',   ['$scope', '$location', 'visitsSvc', '$timeout',    function ($scope, $location, visitsSvc, $timeout) {
$scope.myWorkCount = 0;
$scope.teamworkCount = 0;
$scope.loading = false;

var updateVisitCount = function () {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.$on("cm:myVisitsReceived", function (event, args) {
        $timeout(function () {
            if (args.data) {
                $scope.myWorkCount = args.data.length;
            }
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    });

    $scope.$on("cm:teamVisitsReceived", function (event, args) {
        $timeout(function () {
            if (args.data) {
                $scope.teamworkCount = args.data.length;
            }
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    });

    visitsSvc.getMyVisits();
    visitsSvc.getTeamVisits();
}

if ($scope.userInfo.isAuthenticated && !$scope.loading) {
    updateVisitCount();
} else {
    $scope.$on("adal:loginSuccess", function (scope) {
        updateVisitCount();
    });
}
}]);
```

data service:

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('visitsSvc', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {



    $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

    return {
        getMyVisits: function () {
            $http.get(cmSettings.apiUrl + '/api/v1/visits/my').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("cm:myVisitsReceived", { data: data, status: status, success: true });
            })
           .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               $rootScope.$broadcast("cm:myVisitsReceived", { data: data, status: status, success: false });
           });
        },
        getTeamVisits: function () {
            $http.get(cmSettings.apiUrl + '/api/v1/visits/team').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("cm:teamVisitsReceived", { data: data, status: status, success: true });
            })
           .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               $rootScope.$broadcast("cm:teamVisitsReceived", { data: data, status: status, success: false });
           });
        },
        getVisit: function (visitNumber) {
            $http.get(cmSettings.apiUrl + '/api/v1/visits/' + visitNumber).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("cm:visitsReceived", { data: data, status: status, success: true });
            })
           .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               $rootScope.$broadcast("cm:visitsReceived", { data: data, status: status, success: false });
           });;
        },
        search: function (searchTerms) {
            return $http.get(cmSettings.apiUrl + '/api/v1/visits/search/' + searchTerms).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("cm:searchVisitsReceived", { data: data, status: status, success: true });
            })
           .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               $rootScope.$broadcast("cm:searchVisitsReceived", { data: data, status: status, success: false });
           });
        },
    };
}])
```

console output:

```
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
File: authorize
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: login
HTML1200: microsoftonline.com is on the Internet Explorer Compatibility View List ('C:\Users\Micah\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IECompatData\iecompatdata.xml').
File: login
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
File: authorize
HTML1506: Unexpected token.
File: localhost:44300, Line: 115, Column: 1
The returned id_token is not parseable.
The returned id_token is not parseable.
State: 0edacc1d-a253-42ac-8a1d-cf1206ad3beb
State status:true
State is right
renewToken is called for resource:https://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Renew token Expected state: ca98c6f9-7a16-4744-828f-351cffedec9b|https://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Navigate url:https://login.microsoftonline.com/cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=96408f66-4eab-4c44-8e59-eed93746bf8f&resource=https%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2F&state=ca98c6f9-7a16-4744-828f-351cffedec9b%7Chttps%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&nux=1&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.2
Navigate to:https://login.microsoftonline.com/cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=96408f66-4eab-4c44-8e59-eed93746bf8f&resource=https%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2F&state=ca98c6f9-7a16-4744-828f-351cffedec9b%7Chttps%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&nux=1&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.2&prompt=none&login_hint=Test1%40cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com&domain_hint=cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com&nonce=220c7d60-d07a-449d-bbcf-dd4cd053365a
LoadFrame: adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
renewToken is called for resource:https://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Renew token Expected state: ca355b60-742a-48c2-8b8c-cd46a1b9b620|https://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Navigate url:https://login.microsoftonline.com/cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=96408f66-4eab-4c44-8e59-eed93746bf8f&resource=https%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2F&state=ca355b60-742a-48c2-8b8c-cd46a1b9b620%7Chttps%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&nux=1&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.2
Navigate to:https://login.microsoftonline.com/cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=96408f66-4eab-4c44-8e59-eed93746bf8f&resource=https%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2F&state=ca355b60-742a-48c2-8b8c-cd46a1b9b620%7Chttps%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&nux=1&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.2&prompt=none&login_hint=Test1%40cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com&domain_hint=cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com&nonce=c204e5c3-9d07-42e3-9787-2e340935ab8c
LoadFrame: adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
LoadFrame: adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
renewToken is called for resource:https://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Renew token Expected state: fdc47862-650b-411b-b59f-98cbf13b5715|https://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Navigate url:https://login.microsoftonline.com/cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=96408f66-4eab-4c44-8e59-eed93746bf8f&resource=https%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2F&state=fdc47862-650b-411b-b59f-98cbf13b5715%7Chttps%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&nux=1&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.2
Navigate to:https://login.microsoftonline.com/cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=96408f66-4eab-4c44-8e59-eed93746bf8f&resource=https%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2F&state=fdc47862-650b-411b-b59f-98cbf13b5715%7Chttps%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&nux=1&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.2&prompt=none&login_hint=Test1%40cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com&domain_hint=cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com&nonce=2f110029-8c7a-4584-aaae-b9a68284b3d9
LoadFrame: adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
LoadFrame: adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
renewToken is called for resource:https://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Renew token Expected state: 46dce352-c78b-453e-993d-7b43dbfee4c0|https://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Navigate url:https://login.microsoftonline.com/cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=96408f66-4eab-4c44-8e59-eed93746bf8f&resource=https%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2F&state=46dce352-c78b-453e-993d-7b43dbfee4c0%7Chttps%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&nux=1&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.2
Navigate to:https://login.microsoftonline.com/cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=96408f66-4eab-4c44-8e59-eed93746bf8f&resource=https%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2F&state=46dce352-c78b-453e-993d-7b43dbfee4c0%7Chttps%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&nux=1&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.2&prompt=none&login_hint=Test1%40cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com&domain_hint=cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com&nonce=ef3226f4-0c07-4dff-ad99-36dde840f7ee
LoadFrame: adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
renewToken is called for resource:https://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Renew token Expected state: e392c56e-5298-41cf-9f0b-4f0bed985b3d|https://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Navigate url:https://login.microsoftonline.com/cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=96408f66-4eab-4c44-8e59-eed93746bf8f&resource=https%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2F&state=e392c56e-5298-41cf-9f0b-4f0bed985b3d%7Chttps%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&nux=1&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.2
Navigate to:https://login.microsoftonline.com/cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=96408f66-4eab-4c44-8e59-eed93746bf8f&resource=https%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2F&state=e392c56e-5298-41cf-9f0b-4f0bed985b3d%7Chttps%3A%2F%2FcloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com%2FdataApi&nux=1&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.2&prompt=none&login_hint=Test1%40cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com&domain_hint=cloudMedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com&nonce=c09911ac-c4ff-495f-b0a8-19931c82b902
LoadFrame: adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
State: ca98c6f9-7a16-4744-828f-351cffedec9b|https://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
State status:true
State is right
Fragment has access token
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
LoadFrame: adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
State: 46dce352-c78b-453e-993d-7b43dbfee4c0|https://cloudmedIdentity.onmicrosoft.com/dataApi
State status:true
State is right
Fragment has access token
```

Comment: Looks like it is related to an angular bug https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1417

Answer (score 0):

You can set AzureAD:true to one of the routes that you want to protect. Adal will start the login and load this protected route after login finishes. When page displays, you can call webapi methods. You don't need loginSuccess event here.

Do you see loginSuccess event firing multiple times in your setup?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Getting back to this issue this week. I do not see the event fire more than once. The entire app/page is loading more than once. Still not sure what is causing it.

Comment: I see this in the console once per page load:Add     adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://app.cloudmedsolutions.com/api

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by the ADAL js team: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1417